# %in% works at console but not in script

Tags: r, console

I have data like the following in a very large tibble "dt":

```
pr1   pr2  pr3  att_id
736  7569  7534 MD029374E
741    NA    NA MD020067E
741  7534    NA MD025172E
741  6639    NA MD045509E
736  7532    NA MD023417E
736  7309  7534 MD026105E
741  7534    NA MD028400L
736  7534    NA MD034753E
```

And this code:

```
sections = c(740, 741, 742, 744)
i = 1
cx_col = 5

for (i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
        k = 1
        for (k in 1:3) {
            dt[i, cx_col] <- (dt[i, k] %in% sections)
        }
}
```

which produces this (wrong) output:

```
pr1   pr2  pr3  att_id    cx
736  7569  7534 MD029374E FALSE
741    NA    NA MD020067E FALSE
741  7534    NA MD025172E FALSE
741  6639    NA MD045509E FALSE
736  7532    NA MD023417E FALSE
736  7309  7534 MD026105E FALSE
741  7534    NA MD028400L FALSE
736  7534    NA MD034753E FALSE
```

It should look like this:

```
pr1   pr2  pr3  att_id    cx
736  7569  7534 MD029374E FALSE
741    NA    NA MD020067E TRUE
741  7534    NA MD025172E TRUE
741  6639    NA MD045509E TRUE
736  7532    NA MD023417E FALSE
736  7309  7534 MD026105E FALSE
741  7534    NA MD028400L TRUE
736  7534    NA MD034753E FALSE
```

HOWEVER, if I type the exact same code, line by line, at the console, the data file ends up the way I want it to.

Why doesn't my code perform in the script as it does on the console?

Note that the sample data I provided doesn't have items from "sections" in pr2 or pr3, but that is just coincidence.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I had no idea there was anything left over from 2013 for me to mark complete. As for the SQL question, although it has been answered in part, the answer doesn't solve the entire problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
dt$cx <- apply(dt[,1:3], 1, function(row) any(row %in% sections) )
dt
  pr1  pr2  pr3    att_id    cx
1 736 7569 7534 MD029374E FALSE
2 741   NA   NA MD020067E  TRUE
3 741 7534   NA MD025172E  TRUE
4 741 6639   NA MD045509E  TRUE
5 736 7532   NA MD023417E FALSE
6 736 7309 7534 MD026105E FALSE
7 741 7534   NA MD028400L  TRUE
8 736 7534   NA MD034753E FALSE
```

---

Edit: and just in case you want to understand the coding mistake better, your code would work if you wrote it in the following way:

```
dt[,5] <- FALSE # instantiate the column and populate with FALSE
for (i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
  k = 1
  for (k in 1:3) {
    dt[i, 5] <- ((dt[i, k] %in% sections) | dt[i, 5]) 
# notice the additional OR dt[i,cx_col] construct here.
# This makes sure that previous "TRUE"s do not get overwritten.
  }
}
```

However, as should be clear from the many answers here, you would not write code like this in R. (If this was Python, we would say your code is not very Pythonic; maybe I should say it is not very Rtistic.)

Comment: Note that this use of `apply` on a `data.frame` will result in unnecessary coercion of the frame to a `character matrix`, and though it should still work with `%in%`, it should be done with caution. If you're going to use `apply`, you should only do it on the columns that are important (and ideally of the same `class`), perhaps `apply(dt[1:3], 1, ...)`.

Comment: Plus-one "Rtistic", and plus-one for the `| dt[i,5]` (which is anti-R but at least semantically better than before).

Comment: Note that I do not recommend the second approach. This was only pedagogical so that the OP understands where the logic went wrong.

Comment: Agreed ... but often it is informative to show how to do it "in the literal way" before moving on to the R-centric (dare I say "Rtistic") way, so it's great that you included it here. (You should totally trademark that word *now* ... ;-)

Comment: I am all for open-source. Let's make `Rtistic` a thing!

Comment: Oh, excellent. You are right, and it solves the problem. When I typed the code in at the console, I was skipping values of "k" that I could see weren't matches. That's why I couldn't see the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I suspect there is more you are not telling us. The problem is not that `%in%` is *not* finding the numbers from `$pr1` in `sections`, it **is** finding it there, as shown by:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
  for (k in 1:1) { # only looking at the first column here
    dt[i, cx_col] <- (dt[i, k] %in% sections)
  }
}
dt
#   pr1  pr2  pr3    att_id    V5
# 1 736 7569 7534 MD029374E FALSE
# 2 741   NA   NA MD020067E  TRUE
# 3 741 7534   NA MD025172E  TRUE
# 4 741 6639   NA MD045509E  TRUE
# 5 736 7532   NA MD023417E FALSE
# 6 736 7309 7534 MD026105E FALSE
# 7 741 7534   NA MD028400L  TRUE
# 8 736 7534   NA MD034753E FALSE
```

Notice that I'm only iterating over the first column (stupid to have a `for` loop for that, but I kept the format for reference).

However, you are *overwriting* the value of `df[i,xc_col]` with each comparison, so since `k=1` is the first checked, it sets `dt[*,5]` to `TRUE`, but when `k=3` (who cares about 2 at this point) it is over-written with `FALSE`.

If your intent is to look for any of the first three columns (a big row-wise "or"), then something like this will work. BTW: no loops required.

```
dt[[cx_col]] <- rowSums(sapply(dt[1:3], `%in%`, sections)) > 0
dt
#   pr1  pr2  pr3    att_id    V5
# 1 736 7569 7534 MD029374E FALSE
# 2 741   NA   NA MD020067E  TRUE
# 3 741 7534   NA MD025172E  TRUE
# 4 741 6639   NA MD045509E  TRUE
# 5 736 7532   NA MD023417E FALSE
# 6 736 7309 7534 MD026105E FALSE
# 7 741 7534   NA MD028400L  TRUE
# 8 736 7534   NA MD034753E FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're doing when you run it line by line, but you're doing *SOMETHING* different.

For each row, you do this:

```
for (k in 1:3) {
    dt[i, cx_col] <- (dt[i, k] %in% sections)
  }
```

That's going to loop over each of the first three columns of row i and see if it's in `sections`. Your second and third columns don't ever seem to be in `sections`... I don't think that's what you want. I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
dt <- tibble::tribble(~pr1 ,  ~pr2,  ~pr3  ,~att_id,
             736,  7569,  7534 ,"MD029374E",
             741,NA,NA,"MD020067E",
             741,  7534,NA,"MD025172E",
             741,  6639,NA,"MD045509E",
             736,  7532,NA,"MD023417E",
             736,  7309,  7534 ,"MD026105E",
             741,  7534,NA,"MD028400L",
             736,  7534,NA,"MD034753E")

sections = c(740, 741, 742, 744)
i = 1
cx_col = 5

for (i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
  ## notice I removed the second loop over each column
  dt[i, cx_col] <- (dt[i, 1] %in% sections)
}

dt
#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#>     pr1   pr2   pr3 att_id    V5   
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <lgl>
#> 1   736  7569  7534 MD029374E FALSE
#> 2   741    NA    NA MD020067E TRUE 
#> 3   741  7534    NA MD025172E TRUE 
#> 4   741  6639    NA MD045509E TRUE 
#> 5   736  7532    NA MD023417E FALSE
#> 6   736  7309  7534 MD026105E FALSE
#> 7   741  7534    NA MD028400L TRUE 
#> 8   736  7534    NA MD034753E FALSE
```

if you wanted to do this in a `dplyr` data pipe, it would look something like this:

```
dt %>%
  mutate(cx_col = case_when(pr1 %in% sections ~ TRUE, 
                            TRUE ~ FALSE)) ->
  output_df
output_df
#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#>     pr1   pr2   pr3 att_id    cx_col
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <lgl> 
#> 1   736  7569  7534 MD029374E FALSE 
#> 2   741    NA    NA MD020067E TRUE  
#> 3   741  7534    NA MD025172E TRUE  
#> 4   741  6639    NA MD045509E TRUE  
#> 5   736  7532    NA MD023417E FALSE 
#> 6   736  7309  7534 MD026105E FALSE 
#> 7   741  7534    NA MD028400L TRUE  
#> 8   736  7534    NA MD034753E FALSE
```

Comment: I provided only a tiny piece of the data file. Items matching "sections" can show up in any of the 3 columns.

Comment: And you're right, I was doing something different--skipping k's that I knew weren't matches.